# sql db2 join with 1 table with some null values

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables : `ar` and `ao`

All items (articlenumbers) exist in `ar` but some don't exist in `ao` or don't exist with value `aotlkd="F"`

I tried :

```
select ao.aoarom, ar.ararnr , ar.ararir, ar.ararkc 
from ao 
  join ar on ao.aoarnr=ar.ararnr 
WHERE ar.ARARNR = '"+ articlenumber+"' 
 and ao.aotlkd='F'
```

Tried it with left and right join and outer join also , which doesn't make a difference.

I would like it to return null for `aoarom` when `ao` doesn't exist or `aotlkd` is not `"F"`, and also return values for `ararnr, ararir, ararkc` in that case

Now it doesn't return anything when `ao` doesn't exist or `aotlkd` is not `"F"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ao.aoarom, ar.ararnr , ar.ararir, ar.ararkc 
from ar left join (SELECT * FROM ao WHERE ao.aotlkd='F') as ao on ao.aoarnr=ar.ararnr 
WHERE ar.ARARNR = '"+ articlenumber+"'
```

is what I would make of your spec.  However, that spec ("I would like it to return null for aoarom when ao doesn't exist or aotlkd is not "F", and also return values for ararnr, ararir, ararkc in that case") really is way too imprecise to be sure of what it is *exactly* that you want/need/expect.

Comment: Oh yeah, before I forget ...  Don't forget to guard yourself against SQL injections and turn that ' "+articlenumber+" ' into a parameterized query of the form "WHERE ar.ARARNR = ?"  (I don't know the right syntax for DB2 but it's for expressing the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
select aoarom, ararnr , ararir, ararkc 
from ao 
LEFT join
     ar 
on   ao.aoarnr = ar.ararnr 
and  ARARNR    = '"+ articlenumber+"' 
and  aotlkd    = 'F'
```

BTW it would help us understand if you prefixed `ARARNR` and `aotlkd` with the table name so we knew which table those columns are in.

Comment: Tried your select, but it doesn't work.I'm getting something completely wrong. Meanwhile I added the table names.

Comment: I didn't read your question too carefully as it was not very well written. Still this is not a difficult problem to solve if you are clear about what you want.  Erwin's answer is good.